# how to restore backup file in room database easily?

Tags: android, database

I can't Find a good Solution For this. Even I Don't Know Anything About taking BackUp And Restore BackUp File in Room DataBase. Please Help Me How to Do it.

I Don"t Have Any Longer Question But Stack OverFlow Giving me Error That's why I wrote this Line

I found Way to take Back up But I Can't found the solution for restore database
when I check app shows restore success but in real data not available in app

```
 public static boolean backUpDatabase(Context context) throws IOException {
        db.close();
        File dbFile = new File(String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath(MainDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)));
        File sDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"Tuition App2");
        String fileName = "TuitionApp_BackUp.db";
        String sfPath = sDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName;
        if (!sDir.exists()){
            sDir.mkdirs();
        }
        File saveFile = new File(sfPath);
        if (saveFile.exists()){
            saveFile.delete();
        }
        if (saveFile.createNewFile()){
            int bufferSize = 8 * 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytes_read = bufferSize;
            OutputStream saveDb = new FileOutputStream(sfPath);
            InputStream inDb = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
            while ((bytes_read = inDb.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0) {
                saveDb.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            saveDb.flush();
            inDb.close();
            saveDb.close();
//saving path in to sharedPraf  sm is object of that class
            sm.saveBackFileName(context,sfPath);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static boolean restoreDataBase(Context context) throws FileNotFoundException {
        db.close();
        File sDir = new File(sm.getBackupFileName(context));
        File finalFile = new File(sDir.getAbsolutePath());
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(finalFile));
        File oldDb = context.getDatabasePath(MainDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);
        if ( inputStream!= null){
            try {
                copyFile((FileInputStream) inputStream,new FileOutputStream(oldDb));
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    public static void copyFile(FileInputStream fromFile, FileOutputStream toFile) throws IOException {
        FileChannel fromChannel = null;
        FileChannel toChannel = null;
        try {
            fromChannel = fromFile.getChannel();
            toChannel = toFile.getChannel();
            fromChannel.transferTo(0, fromChannel.size(), toChannel);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (fromChannel != null) {
                    fromChannel.close();
                }
            } finally {
                if (toChannel != null) {
                    toChannel.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is with SQLite, but the process should be the same:

https://medium.com/@gavingt/refactoring-my-backup-and-restore-feature-to-comply-with-scoped-storage-e2b6c792c3b

Following this will also show you how to comply with scoped storage, because the way you're doing it now won't work at all on Android 11:

https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage

You'll also likely want to disable write-ahead logging in `onOpen()`. This is what it looks like in SQLite:

```
    @Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    //disable write-ahead logging to make backup/restore work on all devices.
    db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
}
```

See this link for where to put the `onOpen()` callback in Room:

https://medium.com/@srinuraop/database-create-and-open-callbacks-in-room-7ca98c3286ab